# MongoDB remove a subdocument document from a subdocument

Tags: c#, mongodb

I use 10gen C# driver for MongoDB and I would like to remove a subdocument from a subdocument. I don't know how to do it.

Here's an example of what looks like my document

```
{
  "_id": "binary_stuff",
  "Name": "MyApplication",
  "Settings": [
    {
      "_id": "binary_stuff",
      "Key": "ImportDirectory",
      "Value": "C:\data",
      "Overrides": [{
             "_id": "binary_stuff",
             "Name": "PathDirectory",
             "Value": "C:\anotherData"
       }]
    },
}
```

And I want to delete the Override which Name is PathDirectory. Here's the query I wrote but it doesn't work. I have no error.

```
var query = Query.And(Query.EQ("_id", applicationId), Query.EQ("Settings.Key", "ImportDirectory"), Query.EQ("Settings.$.Overrides.Name", "PathDirectory"));
Run(database => database.Applications().Remove(query));
```

Thanks for any help.
John

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you should to use $pull operation for delete item from array.

```
        var query = Query.And(Query.EQ("_id", applicationId),
                         Query.EQ("Settings.Key",  "ImportDirectory"));
        var update = Update.Pull("Settings.$.Overrides", new BsonDocument(){
            { "Name", "PathDirectory" }
        });
        database.Applications().Update(query, update);
```

Comment: I tried with this query with your code : var query = Query.And(Query.EQ("_id", applicationId), Query.EQ("Settings.Key", "ImportDirectory")); but it does nothing

Comment: This time, the override is still not removed, but instead I have another subdocument Settings[0]: {} at the Settings level. Look this document: 

{
  "_id": "binary_stuff",
  "Name": "MyApplication",
  "Settings": [
    {
      "_id": "binary_stuff",
      "Key": "ImportDirectory",
      "Value": "C:\data",
      "Overrides": [{
             "_id": "binary_stuff",
             "Name": "PathDirectory",
             "Value": "C:\anotherData"
       }],
   "Settings[0]": {},
    },
}

Comment: And if I try this query: var query = Query.And(Query.EQ("_id", applicationId), Query.EQ("Settings.Key", "ImportDirectory"), Query.EQ("Settings.$.Overrides.Name", "PathDirectory")); Nothing happens

Comment: @John Smith: plz, try to check last solution

Comment: Thanks Andrei. For me the following syntax worked. 
 
 `var query = Query.And(Query.EQ("_id", applicationId),
                         Query.EQ("Settings.Key",  "ImportDirectory"));
        var update = Update.Pull("Settings.Overrides", new BsonDocument(){
            { "Name", "PathDirectory" }
        });
        database.Applications().Update(query, update);`.

  Note that the "$" sign is missing in the pull statement.