# Remove from subdocument from mongodb version 2.4 by id

Tags: c#, mongodb, nested

This is my document

```
Post{
  "_id" : 1,
  "Code" : CSUUID("ba22a2a3-e6b5-4ce6-a3ad-20e5196cca46"),
  "Zip" : 123456,
  "Text" : "Hello",
  "Tags" : [{
      "_id" : 1,
      "Tag" : "Tag8"
    }, {
      "_id" : 2,
      "Tag" : "Tag9"
    }, {
      "_id" : 3,
      "Tag" : "Tag10"
    }]
}
```

I need to delete one of 'Tags' by id in c#.
for example: `delete from post where tag.id = 2`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I delete nested array element in a mongodb document with the c# driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28585206/how-can-i-delete-nested-array-element-in-a-mongodb-document-with-the-c-sharp-dri)

Comment: it is not my answer ! it does not works in this version. I saw it before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> MongoDB.Bson version : 2.0.1.27
>
> MongoDB.Driver version :2.2.0.262
>
> MongoDB.Driver.Code version :2.2.0.262

```
const int id = 1;
var pull = Builders<Post>.Update.PullFilter(x => x.Tags, a => a.Id == id);
var filter1 = Builders<Post>.Filter.And(Builders<Post>.Filter.Eq(a => a.Id, 1), Builders<Post>.Filter.ElemMatch(q => q.Tags, t => t.Id == id));
collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter1, pull);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
var pull = Update<Post>.Pull(x => x.Tags, builder => builder.EQ(q => q.Id, 2)).ToBsonDocument();
var filter1 = Builders<Post>.Filter.And(Builders<Post>.Filter.Eq(a => a.Id, 1),
              Builders<Post>.Filter.ElemMatch(q => q.Tags, t => t.Id == 2));
collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter1, pull);
```

Comment: I think you can find some better way than `Update`, but I'm not an expert in this ;).